# Python Error"TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found"

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

The purpose of this code is to make a program that searches a persons name (on Wikipedia, specifically) and uses keywords to come up with reasons why that person is significant.
I'm having issues with this specific line "if fact_amount < 5 and (terms in sentence.lower()):" because I get this error ("TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found")
If you could offer some guidance it would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
    import requests
    import nltk
    import re

    #You will need to install requests and nltk
    terms = ['pronounced'
    'was a significant'
    'major/considerable influence'
    'one of the (X) most important'
    'major figure'
    'earliest'
    'known as'
    'father of' 
    'best known for' 
    'was a major']
names = ["Nelson Mandela","Bill Gates","Steve Jobs","Lebron James"]
#List of people that you need to get info from
for name in names:
print name
print '==============='
#Goes to the wikipedia page of the person
r = requests.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s' % (name))
#Parses the raw html into text
raw = nltk.clean_html(r.text)
#Tries to split each sentence.
#sort of buggy though
#For example St. Mary will split after St.
sentences = re.split('[?!.][\s]*',raw)
fact_amount = 0
for sentence in sentences:
    #I noticed that important things came after 'he was' and 'she was'
    #Seems to work for my sample list
    #Also there may be buggy sentences, so I return 5 instead of 3
    if fact_amount < 5 and (terms in sentence.lower()):
        #remove the reference notation that wikipedia has
        #ex [ 33 ]
        sentence = re.sub('[ [0-9]+ ]', '', sentence)
        #removes newlines
        sentence = re.sub('\n', '', sentence)
        #removes trailing and leading whitespace
        sentence = sentence.strip()
         fact_amount += 1
        #sentence is formatted. Print it out
        print sentence + '.'
 print
```

Comment: This is a good reason to upgrade to Python 3 if you can - it gives the more informative error `'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list` rather than a misleading one about Unicode.

Comment: @lvc: `"need string or buffer, list found"` seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking it the other way

```
sentence.lower() in terms
```

`terms` is list and `sentence.lower()` is a string. You can check if a particular string is there in a list, but you cannot check if a list is there in a string.

Answer (score 2):

you might mean `if any(t in sentence_lower for t in terms)`, to check whether any terms from `terms` list is in the `sentence` string.

Comment: When it's  "if any (terms in sentence_lower for t in terms()):" I get this error "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
"

Comment: @Chris16: do you see parentheses `()` after `terms` in my code?

Comment: Ah, my bad didn't catch that. I did fix it though, now I have a "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0144' in position 157: character maps to <undefined>" though.

Comment: @Chris16: let's fix one error at a time. Create *minimal* code example that shows your problem and include the full traceback. Update your question or create a new one.